# ¿Cómo compruebo si las tres primeras columnas de un fichero son iguales?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, shell-script

Tengo problemas al conseguir sacar este script de Linux, tengo clara más o menos la idea de cómo llevarlo a cabo pero no me acaba de funcionar.
Os dejo el enunciado del ejercicio y el código que llevo.

Se supone que hay que comprobar 3 columnas y tener en el fichero solo 1 por tanto el programa esta hecho para que de error, la cosa es que no se exactamente como implementar dos "fi" y como arreglar para que me mire dos veces los condicionales para comparar la primera columna con las otras dos

> Realiza un script que compruebe si las tres primeras columnas de un fichero (que contiene solamente una línea) son iguales o diferentes. El nombre del fichero se le debe pedir al usuarios y si no es un fichero que se pueda leer dar un mensaje de error.

```
#!/bin/bash 
read -p "Dime el nombre del fichero y su formato: "fichero
if [ -e $fichero ] && [ -r $fichero ];
then
echo "Existe y se puede leer"
if [ $(cut -f 1- -d /home/estudiante/Desktop/palabra3.txt = $(cut -f 2- -d /home/estudiante/Desktop/palabra3.txt) ];
then
echo "Las columnas son iguales"
else
then
echo "Las columnas son diferentes"

fi
```

Comment: Hola user, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Del código que llevas, ¿Cuál es el problema? Explica qué errores o problemas te genera ese codigo para poder ayudarte sobre ello. Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Solamente tienes un `fi`, por lo que este código como mínimo no funciona. Pégalo en https://www.shellcheck.net/ para ver los detalles más relevantes. Además, sería bueno que le dieras formato, tabulando los `if` y demás; de este modo te será mucho más fácil ver qué cojea. Una vez hecho esto, ya nos podremos centrar en la implementación en sí.

Comment: Por otra parte, sería bueno ver un ejemplo de ficheros que contemplas. ¿Y si tienes más de tres columnas? Ahora mismo solo compruebas dos. ¿Cuál es el delimitador de las columnas?

Comment: Se supone que hay que comprobar 3 columnas y tener en el fichero solo 1 por tanto el programa esta hecho para que de error, la cosa es que no se exactamente como implementar dos "fi" y como arreglar para que me mire dos veces los condicionales para comparar la primera columna con las otras dos

Answer (score 2):

Antes de nada, es bueno comentar que esto con `awk` sería apenas una línea:

```
awk 'NR==1 && $1==$2 && $2==$3 {exit 0} {exit 1}' "$fichero" && echo "igual" || echo "diferentes"
```

Pero como estamos en Bash, debemos *rascar* un poco más:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Dime el nombre del fichero y su formato: " fichero
echo "leí $fichero"
if [ ! -e "$fichero" ] || [ ! -r "$fichero" ]; then
   echo "errorrrrr"
   exit
fi

read -r uno dos tres _ < "$fichero"

if [ "$uno" == "$dos" ] && [ "$dos" == "$tres" ]; then
   echo "iguales"
else
   echo "diferentes"
fi
```

La primera parte es equivalente a la que ya tenías: lee el nombre del fichero y luego valida si existe y es leíble. Fíjate en el matiz de que si esto falla, salgo; así sigo ejecutando el programa en el caso que me interesa, sin estar metido dentro de un *if*. Fíjaate también que uso `"$fichero"`, es decir, pongo comillas dobles al hablar de la variable. Esto es importante porque el contenido podría tener espacios y, sin comillas, todo fallaría.

Luego viene la *chicha* interesante:

```
read -r uno dos tres _ < "$fichero"
```

Esto lee las tres primeras columnas de la primera línea del fichero y las guarda, respectivamente, en las variables `$uno`, `$dos` y `$tres`. En `$_` se guarda el resto, que no nos interesa.

Si las columnas estuvieran separadas por algún campo específico, lo indicaríamos con `IFS` (internal field separator, es decir, separador interno de campos):

```
$ IFS=";" read -r uno dos tres _ <<< "hola;que;tal;estas"
$ echo "$uno"
hola
```

Luego es simplemente cuestión de comparar estas cadenas:

```
if [ "$uno" == "$dos" ] && [ "$dos" == "$tres" ];
```